# how does peer know his transaction validation result are not consistent with other peers in Hyperledger fabric v1.0?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

for loose endorsement policy, for same transaction, even if correct-behavior committers, different committer maybe have different validation result due to their different world state.

And how do commiter know who's validation result is correct(major) or wrong(minor) ?

Hint: at a moment, due to network delay, correct commiter may have different world state.

thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have got it!

because each correct commiter receive block/transaction in exactly same order, and implement same endorsement policy, so that at same transaction's validation moment, all correct commiter indeed have exactly same world state, despite at not same time!

key point is : 
(1) at same moment, different commiters may have different world state due to network delay, etc; 
(2) but, different commiter do validation for same transaction at not same moment.